# HTML child selector with predefined parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a function where `input` element triggers `ng-blur` method with `$event` parameter:

```
$scope.MarkField = function(event)
{
}

<tr>
     <td><input type="text" value="1" id="inputQuantity" ng-blur="MarkField($event);"></td>
     <td><input type="text" value="1" id="inputBruto"></td>
     <td><input type="text" value="1" id="inputNeto"></td>
</tr>
```

What I need to do is find values of other two inputs (inputBruto and inputNeto) in this row when ng-blur is clicked. How to do this?

**EDIT:**

I am passing `$event` parameter because I know I can do something like this:

`$(event.target).parent().parent()` - the row where all three inputs are.

But I don't know how to use this row later to get input by id.

It would be nice if something like this is possible:

```
$("#rowID > td > input[id=inputBruto]");
```

**EDIT:**

I've managed to find / change `input[id=inputBruto]` with:

```
$(event.currentTarget).parent().parent().find("input[id=inputBruto]").val("test")
```

Problem solved, thanks for help!

Comment: why are you passing the $event input parameter?do you need it in the coding to be defined in the function?

Comment: Just access `ng-model` of both inputs

Comment: I know that it is possible to find html elements with something like: $("#tblEAN128 > tbody > tr:last > td > input[id=inputBruto]"); But I don't know how to use $event here instead of directly typed id.

Comment: @Rajesh - I don't have ng-model in this table. For this, I would need to instantiate whole table with array of values for each first. I didn't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem.

Read value from input with id=inputBruto:

```
$(event.currentTarget).parent().parent().find("input[id=inputBruto]").val();
```

Write value to input with id=inputBruto:

```
$(event.currentTarget).parent().parent().find("input[id=inputBruto]").val(7);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
$scope.MarkField = function($event)
{
    /* to get tr element */
    var parent = $event.currentTarget.parent().parent()
    var idCurrent = $event.target.id;
    /*from parent finding for #inputBruto & #inputNeto */
    var secInput=parent.querySelector("#inputBruto").value;
    var thirdInput=parent.querySelector("#inputNeto").value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, find parent of the clicked element and find in that your id elements

```
$scope.MarkField = function($event)
{
 var parent=$event.target.parent();
 var secInput=parent.find("#inputBruto").val();
 var thirdInput=parent.find("#inputNeto").val();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript and access the ids using the following code ,

```
$scope.MarkField = function($event)
{
var idCurrent=$event.target.id;
var secInput=document.getElementById("inputBruto").value;
var thirdInput=document.getElementById("inputNeto").value;
}
```

You can also use jquery in the same manner as shown below,

```
 $scope.MarkField = function($event)
{
var idCurrent=$event.target.id;
var secInput=$("#inputBruto").val();
var thirdInput=$("#inputNeto").val();
}
```

Comment: $("#inputBruto").val() always returns first id that it finds in the table. There are many rows and I need to find #inputBruto in the row which is currently being edited.

Comment: ok that means there are many input elements in your table with the id="inputBruto" isn't it?

Comment: Yes, each row has one.